# Thrust device management and kernel

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm using Thrust in my current project so I don't have to write a `device_vector` abstraction or (segmented) scan kernels myself.

So far I have done all of my work using thrust abstractions, but for simple kernels or kernels that don't translate easily to the for_each or transform abstractions I'd prefer at some point to write my own kernels instead.

So my question is: Can I through Thrust (or perhaps CUDA) ask which device is currently being used and what properties it has (max block size, max shared memory, all that stuff)?

If I can't get the current device, is there then some way for me to get thrust to calculate the kernel dimensions if I provide the kernel registers and shared memory requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the current device with CUDA.  See the CUDA documentation on [device management](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html). Look for `cudaGetDevice()`, `cudaSetDevice()`, `cudaGetDeviceProperties()`, etc.

Thrust has no notion of device management currently. I'm not sure what you mean by "get thrust to calculate the kernel dimensions", but if you are looking to determine grid dimensions for launching your custom kernel, then you need to do that on your own. It can help to query the properties of the kernel with [`cudaFuncGetAttributes()`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__EXECUTION_ge89e3ebfbbdfa352b048c7d19904fc1b.html#ge89e3ebfbbdfa352b048c7d19904fc1b), which is what Thrust uses.

Comment: Looks like Jared and I answered at the same time. :)

Comment: Presumably @asger is interested in functionality which would select a kernel's launch configuration on his behalf. If so, no, there is no such functionality exposed by either CUDART or Thrust.

Comment: And in general, providing launch autoconfiguration would be very hard: the CUDA runtime knows nothing about how threads in a kernel cooperate, so it can't easily determine a block size. That requires the programmer's understanding of the code.

Comment: True, for very specialized kernels I would have to do it myself. But for relatively simple kernels that process each element individually, it should be simple to calculate something semi optimal.
I just found a device property struct and some block configuration methods in detail/backend/cuda/arch.h, which I know isn't exactly exposed, but it's there :) I'll see if it gets the job done, otherwise I'll create my own. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @AsgerHoedt: This code may be helpful: https://github.com/jaredhoberock/cuda_launch_config